# Strange case conversion in PostgreSQL 9.5.4

Tags: sql, postgresql, quoted-identifier

```
SELECT AVG(MY_AE_Actual) FROM MY_Data_Details
```

results in an error:

> ERROR:  column "my_ae_actual" does not exist
>   LINE 1: SELECT AVG(MY_AE_Actual) FROM MY_Data_Details
>                      ^
>   HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "my_data_details.my_ae_actual111".
>   ********** Fehler **********
>
> ERROR: column "my_ae_actual" does not exist
>   SQL Status:42703
>   Hinweis:Perhaps you meant to reference the column "my_data_details.my_ae_actual111".
>   Zeichen:12

**Update**

It is quite strange. I tested now in PostgreSQL 10 with following table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.testable
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('testable_id_seq'::regclass),
    string_data1 character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "String_Data2" character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "string_Data3" character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "String_data4" character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT testable_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

`select string_data1 from testable` - success
`select String_data1 from testable` - success
`select string_Data1 from testable` - success
`select String_Data1 from testable` - success
`select "string_data1" from testable` - success
`select "String_data1" from testable` - failure
`select "string_Data1" from testable` - failure
`select "String_Data1" from testable` - failure
`select string_data2 from testable` - failure
`select String_data2 from testable` - failure
`select string_Data2 from testable` - failure
`select String_Data2 from testable` - failure
`select "string_data2" from testable` - failure
`select "String_data2" from testable` - failure
`select "string_Data2" from testable` - failure
`select "String_Data2" from testable` - success

It turns out that without quotes PostgreSQL is not "case insensitive", but "lower casing" which makes no sense at all.

Comment: Could it be that the column is indeed called `my_ae_actual111`?

Comment: Show us create table statement.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Comment: Postgres **is** case insensitive when an unquoted identifier is used (`foo`, `FOO`, `Foo`, `fOo` are all the same identifier. And `"String_Data2"` is something different than `String_Data2` This is well documented [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgresql forces lower case unless you use double quotes so

```
ThisFieldName == thisfieldname
```

But:

```
"ThisFieldName"  <> ThisFieldName
"ThisFieldName"  <> thisfieldname
```

If you create your field like `"ThisFieldName"` you need reference it the same.

In your case you try to use `MY_AE_Actual` but postgresql tell you `my_ae_actual` name doesn't exist.

Sames go for table names.

My suggestion don't use upper case letters in Postgresql. I use all lower case with underscore `_` as separator. But that is just a personal preference.